# How to use TypeScript to make sure two objects have a same structure (without interface)?

Tags: typescript, internationalization

I'm currently working on a web project which heavily utilizes internationalization (i18n) and I have a hard time figuring out how to make sure all languages share exact same keys.

Here's a simple example of `src/lang/en.ts` file:

```js
export default {
  title: "My Website Project",
  description: "This is an example of a file which contains phrases and their keys",
  hello: "Hello!",
};
```

and here's a simple example of `src/lang/id.ts` file:

```js
export default {
  title: "Proyek Website Saya",
  description: "Ini adalah contoh dari sebuah file yang mengandung beberapa frasa beserta kata kuncinya",
  hello: "Halo!",
};
```

Now, I want TypeScript to make sure those files have same keys (not more, not less). So if I put `cat` property into `src/lang/id.ts`, then:

```js
export default {
  title: "Proyek Website Saya",
  description: "Ini adalah contoh dari sebuah file yang mengandung beberapa frasa beserta kata kuncinya",
  hello: "Halo!",
  cat: "Kucing", // <-- this must be error because "cat" doesn't exist in en.ts file!
};
```

But I can't build an interface like this

```js
export default interface LanguageStruct {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  hello: string,
};
```

Because there's hundreds of phrases for each language in the real project and writing those keys one-by-one would be both time consuming and exhausting. I wonder if there's a trick to do with TypeScript for that problem, or at least there's some kind of automation to do that job.

Comment: only way I can think of, is store all the term keys in a separate structure and use this structure as reference in TypeScript

Comment: Well... that means I have to create [an interface](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-interface) which what I need to avoid like what I said at question above. Perhaps, do you have any idea how to automate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keyof typeof someObject` to construct a type from the keys of an object (e.g. the first language strings). Then restrict your other object (the other languages) to have that type as key, and string as value using `Record`. So the type you're looking for is `Record<keyof typeof someObject, string>`. Example:

```
const en = {
  title: "My Website Project",
  description: "This is an example of a file which contains phrases and their keys",
  hello: "Hello!",
};

const de: Record<keyof typeof en, string> = {
  title: "Proyek Website Saya",
  description: "Ini adalah contoh dari sebuah file yang mengandung beberapa frasa beserta kata kuncinya",
  hello: "Halo!",
  cat: "Kucing", // this is highlighted as an error
};
```

See working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmGBeGBvAsAKBjKBLKAGzgC4YAiAWQE8YB1OAIwgLhgAUAnEAKzmCjkANFhwATOBGCc8AB3zgy5ACoALPBBgaYAQ0RwAHjoC2s4jBAAzXTEt5zAd3XBVMUGCg68kGLNWcdCEldMDFcVTg8ThgAazhqCGFRGAjCQhAlAAk4NJAAQiTMAF8Abiwsd2gYCTIAJX4QTjEAHjjqK1xqWTgOhCEYaBkwAHMAPmQ0ZPwiUgouEGo4GPomFig2AGUdah1C8UlpOQUwJQBJMDxdMR1CHVd3KBBXa5kBpgBXO9t7Nh2RmGMCGGejE73+jCYcACsh0tgCEFhEKCnE8sR0qJiYOA3h2exSOXSWRu+TxwHRSgA0u9sSNhDAAPT0mDNAC0LPC2mM7yqEPgnG40QhZO5bHIZME1RAkjAAHJYIYNLBvPAwAA6KCaOzEPJYUrlTBAA).

Comment: Wow that's a quick working solution, thank you! Unfortunately, StackOverflow won't allow me to click that green tick for now. I'll retry next 10 minutes

Comment: no worries, you should wait before accepting an answer anyway, to give others a chance to answer too. but you should be able to upvote if it's helpful to you.

Comment: @Thor-x86_128, this is what I was saying. The reference structure is the original language and you use this as reference for the other languages. I did not say you have to explicitly reference the keys, `keyof` is an automated way

Comment: @NikosM. Oh I see, perhaps you can submit the explanation of your solution as an answer previously. Anyway, thanks for trying to help, I appreciate that